# Are Model objects strictly just a class with the appropriate fields?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvp

I'm pretty new to design patterns and need to implement an MVP architecture for a medium sized project I'm re-doing. I'm a little unclear on the discrepancies between the Presenter and the Model, however.

For example, I've got `UserFile` and `VersionedFile` (inherits from UserFile) as two different Models. Then I have a `FilePresenter` class.

Does the logic that actual manipulates the files belong in the Model, or the Presenter? For example, property validation or a method to copy the file from location to location.

I've read over the wiki article on MVP/MVC and some MSDN links as well, and I *believe* it should all belong in the Presenter. The Model should be "dumb" like the View-- it doesn't do anything but sit there and look pretty. Any and all work is done by the Presenter/Controller, right?

Hope this is objective enough to not be flagged as open-ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the logic that actual manipulates the files belong in the Model, or the Presenter? For example, property validation or a method to copy the file from location to location.

All of that belongs in the `Presenter`; which could also be called a `Controller`. The `Model` is simply built to get the data to the `View`.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I couldn't seem to find an explicit answer. Thanks.

Comment: @sab669, I'm glad I could be of assistance!